# Mistake in Wikipedia CSG example?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars

I'm confused about the example given in Wikipedia article about Context-sensitive grammar:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar

**Disclamer**: I've already changed discussed section in wikipedia article, so current state of article will differ from what I'm discussing in this question. Original version is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Context-sensitive_grammar&oldid=747616366

> The following grammar, with start symbol S, generates the canonical
>   non-context-free language { anbncn : n ≥ 1 } :
>
> 1. S       →       a   b   c
> 2. S   →   a   S   B   c
> 3. c   B   →   W   B
> 4. W   B   →   W   X
> 5. W   X   →   B   X
> 6. B   X   →   B   c
> 7. b   B   →   b   b

They do not claim directly that this grammar **is** *context-sensitive*, but next sentence implies that that they consider it as *context-sensitive*:

> rules 3 to 6 allow for successively exchanging each cB to Bc (four
>   rules are needed for that since a rule cB → Bc wouldn't fit into the
>   scheme αAβ → αγβ)

So they appeal to the canonical form of context-sensitive grammar rules: αAβ → αγβ, implying that whole grammar is context-sensitive.

**What I'm confused about is rule #3**, which seems to be not fitting scheme αAβ → αγβ. I consider terminal $c$ here as part of $\alpha$, variable $B$ as $A$ in scheme, $\beta$ is empty. This implies that $cB$ can not produce $WB$, as $c$ should be saved on same place ($cB\rightarrow c\dots$).

Did I missed something or this grammar was really placed here mistakenly (as it is not real context-sensitive)?

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Looks like we made change in that section of wiki article at same time: I've introduced there proper version of grammar

Comment: Unfortunately, your grammar is wrong. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Context-sensitive_grammar#Wrong_grammar_for_language .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I'm sorry, what's wrong with my grammar (9 rules grammar) which I've placed in new article version? Could you point what rule is wrong?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Ah, do you mean that this grammar can produce "aaa bb cccc" as well?

Comment: Yes. Your grammar is in fact identical to the one discussed on the talk page up to renaming $H$ to $W$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek You are absolutely right. I even know from which paper this mistake arrived. Please look at my new edit, I've introduced additional rule which eliminates this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, a simpler CS grammar is possible.  Here it is:

1. $S \rightarrow ABSc$
2. $S \rightarrow Abc$
3. $BA \rightarrow XA$
4. $XA \rightarrow XY$
5. $XY \rightarrow AY$
6. $AY \rightarrow AB$
7. $A \rightarrow a$
8. $Bb \rightarrow bb$.

A derivation for the string $aaabbbccc$ is

$\Rightarrow_1 ABSc\\\Rightarrow_1 AB\textbf{ABSc}c\\\Rightarrow_2 ABAB\textbf{Abc}cc\\\Rightarrow_3 A\textbf{XA}BAbccc\\\Rightarrow_4 A\textbf{XY}BAbccc\\\Rightarrow_5 A\textbf{AY}BAbccc\\\Rightarrow_6 A\textbf{AB}BAbccc\\\dots\\\Rightarrow_{3-6}AAB\textbf{AB}bccc\\\Rightarrow_{3-6}AA\textbf{AB}Bbccc\\\Rightarrow_{7...}\textbf{aaa}BBbccc\\\Rightarrow_8 aaaB\textbf{bb}ccc\\\Rightarrow_8 aaa\textbf{bb}bccc$

Answer (score 3):

Actually as several viewers agreed original grammar was incorrect. As @EmilJeřábek noticed, there was already discussion of this problem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Context-sensitive_grammar#Wrong_grammar_for_language

So it appears that neither 7-rule grammar (which I was inquiring above in my question), neither 9-rule grammar which was here before and present in other-languages articles, both are incorrect. This 9-rule grammar:

> 1. S       →       a   B   C
> 2. S   →   a   S   B   C
> 3. C   B   →   W   B
> 4. W   B   →   W   C
> 5. W   C   →   B   C
> 6. a   B   →   a   b
> 7. b   B   →   b   b
> 8. b   C   →   b   c
> 9. c   C   →   c   c

is incorrect example as it can produces words of the form "`aaa bb cccc`" `which doesn't fit formula $a^nb^nc^n$.

So I suggest following enhancement of this grammar by replacing rules 3-5 to four rules:

1. S       →       a   B   C
2. S   →   a   S   B   C
3. C   B   →   C   Z
4. C   Z   →   W   Z
5. W   Z   →   W   C
6. W   C   →   B   C
7. a   B   →   a   b
8. b   B   →   b   b
9. b   C   →   b   c
10. c   C   →   c   c

Rules 3-6 will help avoid problem with replacing CB to WB and then WC to BC.

<strike>**EDIT**: As @EmilJeřábek suggested again, rules #7 and #8 can be simplified to one rule $B\rightarrow b$</strike>.